# One partial view on multiple pages

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a Partial View which shows on multiple pages. The problem I am facing after implementing it is, The position of the partial view is beiong shuffled on different views. Each of the views have their own css layout. So, should I change the css layout of all the views or is there any workaround for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would render shared partials like here:

One way to do it is to have two Layouts for your pages.
Have the default _Layout.cshtml and _LayoutWithSomething.cshtml and then in your Views determine which one to use

```
@{
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutWithSomething.cshtml";
}
```

Another way to do this is to put RenderSection block in your _Layout.cshtml

```
        <div class="main-content">
            @RenderSection("submenu", false)
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
```

And then use @section in your views, note that this doesn't work inside partial views.

```
@section submenu
{
     @Html.Partial("_MyPartial")
}
```

If your css completely changes the layout I'd split the css into two: layout aspect of styling and then the others like colors etc.